# Null object error, possibly from not loading foreign key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-6.0

I'm new to asp.net and am experiencing this error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Views_Book_List.ExecuteAsync() in List.cshtml
<td class="text-center">@Category.Name</td>
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I get the error, upon loading the `List` view

*~/Views/Book/List.cshtml*

```
@model IEnumerable<Book>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Books";
}

<div class="container p-3">
    <div class="row pt-4">
        <div class="col-6">
            <h2 class="text-primary">Books List</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 text-end">
                <a asp-controller="Book" asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-primary"><i
                class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i>&nbsp; Create New Book</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
   @{
        int count = Model.Count();
        if(count == 0)
        {
        <em>
            <h3>There are currently no books</h3>
        </em>
        }
        else 
              {
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th> 
                <th>Book Name</th> 
                <th>Category</th> 
                <th>Author</th> 
                <th>Publiser</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @{int i = 0;}
            @foreach (var obj in Model)
            {
                var Category = obj.Category;
                i++;
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center" width=5%>@i</td>
                    <td class="text-center" width="20%">
                        <a asp-controller="Book" asp-action="Index" asp-route-id="@obj.Id">@obj.Name</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-center">@Category.Name</td> // < Problematic line
                    <td class="text-center">@obj.Author</td>
                    <td class="text-center">@obj.Publisher</td>
                    <td class="text-center">@obj.Description</td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        @* <div class="w-75 btn-group text" role="group">
                            <a asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@obj.Id"
                            class="btn btn-primary mx-2">
                                <i class="bi bi-pencil"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit</a>
                            <a asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@obj.Id" 
                            class="btn btn-danger mx-2">
                                <i class="bi bi-trash-fill"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Delete</a>
                        </div> *@
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
        }
    }
</div>
```

This is the part of the controller:

*~/Controllers/BookController.cs*

```cs
    ...
    //GET
    public IActionResult List()
    {
        IEnumerable<Book> objBookList = _db.Books.OrderBy(t => t.Name); ;
        return View(objBookList);
    }
   ...
```

I believe it is because for whatever reason, "Category" is not loaded, even though it is declared in the schema

*~/Models/Book.cs*

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace mymvc.Models;

public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(32)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(32)]
    public string Author { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string Publisher { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(1024)]
    public string Description { get; set; } = "This is a description";
    [DisplayName("Created at")]
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix.

It turns out I needed to enable lazy loading to fix this issue.

Firstly I ran the following command to install the neccessarry proxies

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies
```

Then I added the following to `~/Data/ApplicationDbContext.cs`

```cs
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder
           .UseLazyLoadingProxies();
    }
```

Hey presto!